# Template function with dependent type parameters within template class

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, templates

I've been trying to do this simple stuff and Visual studio 2008 does not seems to like it.

```
template <class CharType>
class SomeClass
{
public:
    template <class T1, class T2>
    static bool SomeOperator(const typename T1::const_iterator& p_Begin1,
                             const typename T1::const_iterator& p_End1,
                             const typename T2::const_iterator& p_Begin2,
                             const typename T2::const_iterator& p_End2)
    {
        // do some stuff..
    }
};
```

And call it with something like this:

```
std::wstring a;
OtherString b;
SomeClass<wchar_t>::SomeOperator(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end());
```

What I get is compiler errors stating that it can't deduce template parameter T1 and T2

```
error C2783: 'bool SomeClass<CharType>::SomeOperator(const T1::const_iterator &,const T1::const_iterator &,const T2::const_iterator &,const T2::const_iterator &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'T1'
error C2783: 'bool SomeClass<CharType>::SomeOperator(const T1::const_iterator &,const T1::const_iterator &,const T2::const_iterator &,const T2::const_iterator &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'T2'
```

Comment: Does the code compile when  you explicitly define the template parameter? So, like 'SomeClass<wchar_t>::SomeOperator<std::wstring, OtherString>(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end());'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is simply unable to deduce types from this context.

Suppose `std::wstring::const_iterator` is actually `const wchar_t*`, which is likely. In that case, how does the compiler know it should substitute `std::wstring` rather than any other type `T` with `T::const_iterator` being `const wchar_t*` (perhaps `vector<wchar_t>`)?

It's impossible for the compiler to tell exactly. For similar reasons, you cannot deduce `some_template<T>::type` in function calls.

In your case, the workaround is easy. You don't actually need the container type - templating on the iterator types will work fine:

```
template <typename I1, typename I2>
static bool SomeOperator(const I1& p_Begin1, const I1& p_End1,
                         const I2& p_Begin2, const I2& p_End2)
  { /* stuff */ }
```

If you find yourself in a situation where you need the container type, you will have to either pass the container around or explicitly specify the type in the function call.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler can't deduce that the iterator parameters are actually inner type defs of the containers providing them.

Use directyl two iterator types:

```
template< typename IT1, typename IT2>
static bool SomeOperator(const IT1& p_Begin1,
                             const IT1& p_End1,
                             const IT2& p_Begin2,
                             const IT2& p_End2)
    {
        // do some stuff..
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to be explicit about the types for `SomeOperator`:

```
SomeClass<wchar_t>::SomeOperator<std::wstring, std::wstring>(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end());
```

I know that seems annoying, but it's actually fairly hard (and at times not possible) for the compiler to deduce the container type from a nested definition like `T::const_iterator`.  Going from `const_iterator` back to `T` isn't straightforward AFAIK.